# How to set preftix and delete after character in each line in txt file with c#

Tags: c#

Hello i'm getting some strings from a Web API 
[Like This](https://api.hackertarget.com/hostsearch/?q=google.com)

```
mail-lf0-f100.google.com,209.85.215.100
mail-vk0-f100.google.com,209.85.213.100
mail-ua1-f100.google.com,209.85.222.100
mail-ed1-f100.google.com,209.85.208.100
mail-lf1-f100.google.com,209.85.167.100
mail-ej1-f100.google.com,209.85.218.100
mail-pj1-f100.google.com,209.85.216.100
mail-wm1-f100.google.com,209.85.128.100
mail-io1-f100.google.com,209.85.166.100
mail-wr1-f100.google.com,209.85.221.100
mail-vs1-f100.google.com,209.85.217.100
mail-ot1-f100.google.com,209.85.210.100
mail-qv1-f100.google.com,209.85.219.100
mail-yw1-f100.google.com,209.85.161.100
```

it give me some string records and i want to do this **Operations**.

1. I want to make it line by line like it show in original
2. I want to remove everything after comma in eachline
3. I want to set a prefix before each line for the example:

**Example:** `Google.com to>>      This is Dns: Google.com`

and This is my code . What should i edit and what should i add?

```
        string filePath = "D:\\google.txt";
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        string html = wc.DownloadString("https://api.hackertarget.com/hostsearch/?q=Google.com");
        File.CreateText(filePath).Close();
        string number = html.Split(',')[0].Trim();
        File.WriteAllText(filePath, number);
        MessageBox.Show("Finish");
```

Comment: please show a bit more of code, we don't know what wc, even though we can guess its a webclient downloading html content, we don't have to. Also, you didn't mention saving anything to a file, if you wan't the output on a file, work on memory until you get what you want and then write to a file with just one `WriteAllText()` that will create/open & write contents & close the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hi**
Thanks to [Derviş Kayımbaşıoğlu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61396449/how-to-set-preftix-and-delete-after-character-in-each-line-in-txt-file-with-c-sh/61396916#61396916)

Also i find my solution from another way

```
        string path = @"D:\Google.txt";
        var url = "https://api.hackertarget.com/hostsearch/?q=google.com";
        var client = new WebClient();
        //StreamWriter myhost = new StreamWriter(path);
        using (var stream = client.OpenRead(url))
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            string line;
            string realString;
            using (StreamWriter myhost = new StreamWriter(path))
            {
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    realString = "This is the dns: " + line.Split(',')[0].Trim();

                    myhost.WriteLine(realString);
                }
            }
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Finish");
```

Answer (score 1):

you are actually close. Check the solution below

```
var filePath = @"C:\Users\Mirro\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Assessment2\Assessment2\act\actors.txt";

WebClient client = new WebClient();
string html = client.DownloadString("https://api.hackertarget.com/hostsearch/?q=google.com");
string[] lines = html.Split(
    new[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n" },
    StringSplitOptions.None
);

var res = lines.Select(x => (x.Split(',')[0]).Trim()).ToList();

//res.Dump();
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(filePath, lines);
```

[.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yLo5wk)